# How to prove that if $x$ is not invertible, then $Rx \neq R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be an associative ring with identity and let $x \in R$ be an element that is not invertible. How can we prove that $Rx \neq R$? Here $Rx$ denotes the left ideal generated by $x$.

Comment: If $R$ is not commutative, this isn't necessarily true: for example, in the ring of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the "right shift" operation $(x_0, x_1, \ldots) \mapsto (0, x_0, x_1, \ldots)$ has a left inverse and thus the left ideal generated by it is the unit ideal; yet the right shift operation is not invertible.

Comment: What is true in general is: if $x \in R$ is not left invertible, then $Rx \ne R$.

Comment: $x \in R$ is not invertible iff $Rx \ne R$ **or** $xR \ne R $

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you! I knew there was something wrong.

Comment: @VitorG. Why did you delete your solution?  It seems to be that you have solved it yourself, and it would be better to have it than not, for purposes of question context.

Comment: @rschwieb I undeleted it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Robert Israel said, the correct statement is "if $x$ is not invertible, then $Rx \neq R$ or $xR \neq R$", and this is easy to prove by the contrapositive: if $Rx = R$ and $xR = R$, then there are $y, z \in R$ such that $xy = 1$ and $zx = 1$, and it is easy to conclude that $y = z$, hence $x$ is invertible.